# MVC logout Button Confirm Modal Popup Not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

Im develop the **MVC** project, Im developed the User **Login** session, Im add the user **logout button** for **bootstrap modal popup** `confirmation` box, but box is not working,How can i fix it.

Thank you

```
<header>
  <a id="header-logo" href="#"></a>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="~/img/ekinitting _logo.png" class="img-responsive" style=" position: absolute; display: block; width: 260px; height: 65px; left: 10px; top: 10px;"></a>

  @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Login", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })){
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" style="  top:-28px;"><input type="image" id="myimage" src="~/img/log_out.png" style=" margin-top:15px; margin-left:150px; position:relative; float:right;  " data-toggle="modal"
       data-target="#basicModal" /></a>

  }
  <div class="col-lg-2" style="color:#ff0000; margin-top:28px; left:1055px; position:relative; ">

     @Html.ActionLink("Hello           " + ((eKnittingData.UserRegistration)Session["User"]).UserName + " :)", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Welcome", style = "color:#fada5b; text-decoration: none; font-size:14px;" })

  </div>
  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  <a href="~/Home/Index">

    <input type="image" id="myimage" src="~/img/Red-home-icon.png" style="top:15px; position:relative; left:150px; float:right; " />

  </a>

</header>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#ffffff; border:solid 4px #e85656;margin-top:253px; left:-25px;">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#e85656; height:15px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:-12px;">x</button>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" style=" color:yellow; font-size:large; top:-10px; left:115px;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center;"></h4>
      </div>
      <p style="text-align:center; font-family:'Ebrima'; color:black; margin-top:15px;"> <strong>  Are you sure you want to logout? </strong></p>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success  btn-xs" style=" width:50px;">Yes</button></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal" style=" width:50px;">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your form inside the modal not to the logout button which is opening the modal.

Just put the form in the modal-body where the confirmation text is written in your code.

All you need to put the form outside to the modal-body and footer div.